# wiresharkデータ（pcap）のデータ解析

Tags: python3, wireshark

python3で　wiresharkデータ（pcap）のデータ解析、抽出をしたいと考えていて、下記のスクリプトで　UDP のsrc,dscやport　をリストアウトできることは確認できたのですが、これに加えて、添付のような（黄色部の）値を取得するにはどのように指定（コード）すれば良いのでしょうか？ ※下記スクリプトに拘っていないので、ご助言お待ちしてます
[image: 取得したい値]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import dpkt, socket
import string
import binascii
import sys

#メイン関数
def main(filename):
    pcr = dpkt.pcap.Reader(open(filename,'rb'))
    #パケット数
    packet_count = 0

    #パケット処理
    for ts,buf in pcr:
        packet_count += 1
        try:
            eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
        except:
            continue

        #IPデータの場合
        if type(eth.data) == dpkt.ip.IP:
            ip = eth.data
            ipheader(ip)
            #TCPデータ
            if type(ip.data) == dpkt.tcp.TCP:
                tcp = ip.data
                #ペイロードが0以外
                if len(tcp.data) != 0:
                    thex = binascii.b2a_hex(tcp.data)
                    payload(thex)
            #UDPデータ
            elif type(ip.data) == dpkt.udp.UDP:
                udp = ip.data
                #ペイロードが0以外
                if len(udp.data) != 0:
                    uhex = binascii.b2a_hex(udp.data)
                    payload(uhex)
            #ICMPデータ
            elif type(ip.data) == dpkt.icmp.ICMP:
                icmp = ip.data
                #ペイロードが0以外
                if len(icmp.data) != 0:
                    ihex = binascii.hexlify(str(icmp.data))
                    payload(ihex[8:])

    print ("処理終了:", packet_count)

#IPヘッダ処理
def ipheader(header):
    #ヘッダの処理
    src = socket.inet_ntoa(header.src)
    dst = socket.inet_ntoa(header.dst)
    if type(header.data) == dpkt.udp.UDP:
        print ("UDP %s:%s => %s:%s (len:%s)" % (src, header.data.sport, dst, header.data.dport, len(header.data.data)))

#ペイロード
def payload(thex):
    #ペイロードの処理
    return
```

*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/_/
追記
スマートな手法ではないですが、現状のノウハウをふまえ・・・
とりあえず　「　wireshark　→　jsonデータ（保存）　→　python解析　」　で　
当面の課題としては取り組むこととしました
BACpypes、tshark　ともに、理解深めて、今後の手法にしたいと思います

Comment: [BACpypes](https://github.com/JoelBender/bacpypes) というパッケージがありますので参考にしてみてはどうでしょうか。パッケージにはサンプルコードも含まれています(例えば `samples/ReadAllProperties.py`)。

Answer (score 2):

wiresharkには、CLI版の`tshark`が同梱されています。
`-V`オプションをつけると、(wiresharkと同じように)パケットの解析結果が出力が出力されるので、そこから(正規表現等を使って)欲しいフィールド値を抽出する方法もあると思います。

```
[PCAPファイルを読み込んで表示させるコマンド例]
tshark -r PCAPファイル -V
```

いかがでしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

`dpkt`というライブラリは、BACnetのパケットの解釈ができるのでしょうか。

ライブラリがサポートしていないプロトコルは、ペイロードの中身をプロトコルに従って**自分で**解釈する必要があります。